# NodeJS with Docker: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/folder/example.key'

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I'm mostly trying to understand how I can troubleshoot/understand how the files are packaged into the docker container when building the NodeJS app. I have a NodeJS project that has the following directory structure:

[image]

The docker file content is as below:

```
FROM node:8.7-alpine as build
RUN npm install --global typescript webpack
ENV NODE_ENV=development NODE_PATH=/app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN tsc -p .
RUN webpack

FROM node:8.7-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV=production NODE_PATH=/app
RUN apk add --no-cache \
    udev \
    ttf-freefont \
    chromium \
    fontconfig pango-dev libxcursor libxdamage cups-libs dbus-libs libxrandr gconf-dev libxscrnsaver libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

COPY --from=build /app/build .
CMD ["node", "."]
```

In the `index.ts` file I have the line:

```
key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './../ssl/example.key'))
```

I tried changing the above line to

```
key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../ssl/example.key'))
```

but didn't work. I also tried moving the ssl directory inside src folder and using the line below still without success:

```
key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'ssl/example.key'))
```

This line causes the following error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/ssl/example.key'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:653:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:554:33)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:15:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:665:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

I suppose this is because of the way the application directories are packaged when put in a docker container. Without docker container it works fine. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of this issue was that I wasn't copying the `ssl` folder during the docker image build. In order to make sure this folder is copied during the build process I needed to add [`COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) to my Dockerfile. So, the final Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM node:8.7-alpine as build
RUN npm install --global typescript webpack
ENV NODE_ENV=development NODE_PATH=/app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN tsc -p .
RUN webpack

FROM node:8.7-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV=production NODE_PATH=/app
RUN apk add --no-cache \
    udev \
    ttf-freefont \
    chromium \
    fontconfig pango-dev libxcursor libxdamage cups-libs dbus-libs libxrandr gconf-dev libxscrnsaver libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app
# This was the missing line:
COPY ssl /ssl
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

COPY --from=build /app/build .
CMD ["node", "."]
```

Comment: But by running install in the second step, you're removing the whole point of build steps, and end up with a larger container.